# I can't get information from a object inside object in React Native iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, json, listview, react-native

i'm learning React Native for iOS

My problem is I can't get information inside of object, is a link of picture.

Code of inside renderRow for listView React Native

```
renderRow(rowData, sectionID, rowID) { 
 console.log(rowData.media.imagenes[0].imagenLink)
```

With that code, shows like this.

[Picture of console.log(rowData.media)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5Bz6.png)

If I write the code like this, that is supposedly to work

```
console.log(rowData.media.imagenes[0].imagenLink)
```

Then, it shows an error.

[Error from Simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMFph.png)

If I write the code outside of renderRow(), it works.

```
console.log(this.state.datosJSON[0].media.imagenes[0].imagenLink)
```

Then I can get a link of picture.

I hope someone can help me.

Regards and thanks for your time

Comment: Can you share `dataSource` in listView.

Comment: Sure, is `constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2})
    this.state = {
      dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(['row 1']),
      datosJSON:''
    };
  }`

Comment: I could fix it, if I use console.log something, it gives me error, but if I use {{ uri }} , it works, I don't know why

Answer (score 0):

Actually i don't know how you do it exactly
.But `renderRow` method was being used like following.First of all you should define `dataSource` into state.

```
getInitialState: function() {
    var ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
    return {
      dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(['row 1', 'row 2']),
    };
  },
```

After that you should use `ListView` through `render` method.

```
  render: function() {
    return (
      <View>
        <ListView
          dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
          renderRow={this._renderRow}
        />
      </View>
    );
  },
```

After that you made these, you can insert to code `renderRow` method.

```
renderRow(rowData, sectionID, rowID) { 
 console.log(rowData.media.imagenes[0].imagenLink);
}
```

I think if you make these ,code will be work properly.